# Finding a global minimum of non-convex quasi-smooth function that is costly to evaluate

Tags: optimization, algorithms, extreme-value

I have a bounded non-convex function in 10-dimensional space. The function is quasi-smooth, you can imagine a histogram, here is an illustration, it just shows the idea and not related to my particular function:

[image]

The function value is obtained by time consuming simulation (it takes about 10 seconds). Obviously if I want compute gradients, I need to approximate them by difference quotients. If you need more details about the function, I might be able to say more.

I have read the article of
L.M. Rios and N.V. Sahinidis, [Derivative-free optimization: A review of algorithms and comparison of software implementations](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10898-012-9951-y.pdf)

So I've tried all of TOMLAB solvers, proposed in article and also [MCS](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/software/mcs/) method, also mentioned in the article as one of the best.
But neither of them could not overperform simple Brent method accompanied by hand picked initial guess (well, I hardly believe I can produce such great guesses).

I've heard about surrogate modeling, is it worth trying?

So which other global optimization methods should I consider?

Comment: May be genetic algorithm or simulated annealing ?

Comment: @forecaster yeah, I've tried simulated annealing as well, but in vain.

Comment: any chance you can post your function ?, you could also try a hybrid global/local optimizer example: GA-nedler mead or Simulated annealing - neadler mead  method ?

Comment: @forecaster no, not a chance, function value is a result of simulation